# Add text in Google Map Markers

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, jquery-gmap2

I have managed to get a google map on my site using Javascript api of google maps.. and it works great...

Each Location/vehicle has a marker which is great. But the problem is I need to display A name in each marker. I receive my data from sql and loading the latitudes and logitudes works great, I just need to change the marker. From the database I get the Driver name, latitude and logitude. I need to display the Driver name in the marker. These data would depend on a site (which is chosen from a dropdownlist). When a call is logged we need to send the nearest technition out to the client.

This is what I have done:

My script in the head:

```
     <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false
             &amp;key=AIzaSyCRuaf5l3GKHKII8uG8TDUFW35xr34PgEw" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

My div for the map:

```
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:Literal ID="js" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin-bottom: 2px;">
            </div>
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>
```

And this is showing the map and adding the positions:

```
            private void BuildScript(DataTable tbl)
    {
        string custLocationLat, custLocationLong;

        String Locations = "";
        string marker;

        if (lblCustLatitude.Text == "")
            custLocationLat = Convert.ToString(-26.172116);
        else
            custLocationLat = Convert.ToString(lblCustLatitude.Text);

        if (lblCustLongtitude.Text == "")
            custLocationLong = Convert.ToString(28.130557);
        else
            custLocationLong = Convert.ToString(lblCustLongtitude.Text);

        marker = "var = new GMarker(new GPoint(" + custLocationLat + ", " + custLocationLong + "));";

        foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
        {   
            if (r["Latitude"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
                continue;

            string Latitude = r["Latitude"].ToString();
            string Longitude = r["Longitude"].ToString();
            string markerPoints = r["DrivName"].ToString();
            int i= 0;

            Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")));";
            marker += Environment.NewLine + "var" + i + " = new GMarker(new GPoint(" + Latitude + ", " + Longitude + "));";
            i++;                
        }

        js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                        function initialize() {                                 
                          if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(" + custLocationLat + "," + custLocationLong + @"), 8); 
                            " + Locations + @";                                 
                            map.setUIToDefault();
                            }
                        }
                        </script> "; 
    }
```

I'm very new to javascript and google maps. If anybody can please lead me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

---

### **ANSWER**

This is the solution:

Code Behind:

```
     public class Marker
{
    public string title;
    public string lat;
    public string lng;
    public string description;
}

    private void BuildScript(DataTable tbl)
    {
        string custLocationLat, custLocationLong;

        List<Marker> valueList = new List<Marker>();                    

        if (lblCustLatitude.Text == "")
            custLocationLat = Convert.ToString(-26.172116);
        else
            custLocationLat = Convert.ToString(lblCustLatitude.Text);

        if (lblCustLongtitude.Text == "")
            custLocationLong = Convert.ToString(28.130557);
        else
            custLocationLong = Convert.ToString(lblCustLongtitude.Text);

        Marker center = new Marker { title = "Smart Office", lat = custLocationLat, lng = custLocationLong, description = "0" };
        List<Marker> marker = new List<Marker>();

        foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
        {   
            if (r["Latitude"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
                continue;

            string Latitude = r["Latitude"].ToString();
            string Longitude = r["Longitude"].ToString();
            string driver = r["DrivName"].ToString();
            string distance = r["Distance"].ToString();

            marker.Add(new Marker { title = driver, lat = Latitude, lng = Longitude, description = distance });          
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        hdnMarkers.Value = ser.Serialize(marker);
    }
```

APS.Net

```
    <script type="text/javascript">       

      var markers = document.getElementById("<%=hdnMarkers.Value%>").value;

      function initialize()
      {      
          var mapOptions = {     
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng), 
              zoom: 8,       
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP         
          };            
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();       
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);  
          var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#FF8200' });     
          var lat_lng = new Array();      
          for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
          {
              var data = markers[i]
              var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
              var marker = new StyledMarker({
                  styleIcon: new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.BUBBLE, { color: "2590BA", text: data.title }),
                  position: myLatlng, map: map, title: data.title
              });

              (function (marker, data)
              {
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                      infoWindow.setContent(data.description); infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
              })(marker, data);
          }
      }   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for **infowindows** and you will be able to get what you want to do. You can display driver name in infowindow when user click on your map marker.
See below links.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows
```

you will find good example here also.
Hope this help :)